# VSFTPD - 0.00Kbyte/sec - intermittent

Tags: iptables, ftp, selinux, vsftpd

I can't get a good connection via FTP to my DigitalOcean server. I set it up following [this guide.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-on-centos-6--2)

Symptoms:

Sometimes I can upload the file I am working on, sometimes I can not. (same file, same permissions, etc.)

Troubleshooting:

The Trace Route and Ping look normal but there is defiantly issues. I also tried to transfer files to FTP via my 4G LTE connection over Verizon and ran into the same issues. Thee log shows the concerning part, a transfer of 0.00Kbyte/sec. I even went as far as disabling SELinux and it still has this issue. I have looked at all forms related to this issue In addition I have the following iptables rule

Technical Info: 
IPTABLES

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -i eth0 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
```

VSFTPD Log

```
Fri Mar 21 12:47:00 2014 [pid 7466] CONNECT: Client "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" 
Fri Mar 21 12:47:00 2014 [pid 7465] [example_user] OK LOGIN: Client "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" 
Fri Mar 21 12:47:58 2014 [pid 7445] [example_user] OK UPLOAD: Client "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "/path/to/files/file.info", 0.00Kbyte/sec
```

vsftpd.config file

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=NO
chroot_local_user=YES
listen=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

Answer (score 0):

for testing;

iptables --flush

drop iptables;

i suspect you have MTU problems.

Lower YOUR client side MTU to 1300.

Let us know if either solves it.

Another option also is use sftpd via ssh - please try the throughput also on that from Filezilla ftp.